# react native Unexpected token while building app

Tags: react-native

[image: Capture or error]

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/mhd/Documents/Projects/testingscrn/node_modules/react-native/screens/HomeScreen.js: Unexpected token (19:3)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() => navigate('Profile', {name: 'Jane'})}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: at last add `}`.

Answer (score 0):

there is ending bracket of your class is missing. It should be like below

```
.....

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() => navigate('Profile', {name: 'Jane'})}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i modified my post with one image pls check error am facing after putting brackets.

Comment: @MohammadHassan I think there is an error of the wrong path where you import your HomeScreen.